# Randomly fill image with unique colors?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, vector, fill, script

In this image, I would like to randomly fill each region with a different color, such that, no two regions have the same color. I've been searching for such a method and have come across a script that will randomly fill in each region with different colors, but in my case I need those colors to be unique.

Is it possible to accomplish this task in Illustrator?

[image]

Comment: Sure, just make a table of unique colors then shuffle the list.

Comment: I think the "Recolor Artwork" feature might be what you're after: [youtube video on it](https://youtu.be/u25xsb8243Y)

Answer (score 1):

boguslavsky's plugin in the other answer looks fantastic.

However, there are also **free** Illustrator scripts available on the web 
if you'd rather not purchase anything.

Here's a YouTube video explaining how to install and use scripts, in case you don't know:
 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QUWWlWP1QkI

One I'll use is called "Vary Hues", you can get from here: 
 http://js4ai.blogspot.com/2012/08/update-to-vary-hues.html

Merely select art and call the script and you can 
choose the number of hues you want, even vary opacity if desired.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Or...

[image]

[image]

I don't know if it fits your needs specifically, but it is a way to randomly alter coloring.

There are more scripts out there for randomizing colors....

- http://vectorboom.com/load/freebies/freescripts/randomswatchesfill/22-1-0-167
- https://www.illustratorscripts.com/scripts/randomize-color/

Answer (score 0):

I've written a randomizer plugin for Illustrator that should be able to accomplish what you're trying to do. It can randomize colors from a range or from a set. Range randomization is unlikely to leave you with any duplicate colors.

Read about it here:
https://randomill.com/illustrator-random-color-script/